# How to run BLE peripheral detection in both foreground and background?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral, ios-bluetooth

I want to trigger some kind of HTTP request using iOS and CoreBluetooth, when RSSI of the required bluetooth device is stronger than some offset value.

```
// Listen to centralManager state
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch(central.state){
    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff:
        stopScanningForPeripherals()
        break
    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn:
        startScanningForPeripherals()
        break
    case CBCentralManagerState.Resetting:
        break
    case CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized:
        break
    case CBCentralManagerState.Unknown:
        break
    case CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported:
        break
    }
}

// Start scanning peripherals
func startScanningForPeripherals(){
    print("Start scanning for peripherals \(cbuuid)")
    if(cbuuid == nil){
        self.centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }else{
        self.centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([cbuuid!], options: nil)
    }
}

// Callback when received scanning results
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("\(RSSI.intValue) \(peripheral.identifier.UUIDString) != \(appSettings.listeningPeripheralIdentifier?.UUIDString)")
    if(!peripheral.identifier.isEqual(appSettings.listeningPeripheralIdentifier)){
        return;
    }
    if(RSSI.intValue == 127 || RSSI.integerValue < appSettings.rssiOffset){
        return;
    }
    httpGateway.postDetectBeacon((appSettings.listeningPeripheralIdentifier?.UUIDString)!, userId: appSettings.userId, callback: { isOk in
        print("Sent detect beacon request")
    })
}

// Stop scanning
func stopScanningForPeripherals(){
    print("Stop scanning for peripherals")
    self.centralManager.stopScan()
}
```

I tried implementing a foreground task version (putting it inside a `UIViewController`) and background task version (putting it inside `AppDelegate` and set background hooks). As a result, the frequency of receiving advertisement packet is much more better on foreground task version. But the foreground task version stops receiving when the app is in the background, and I also want the work to be done even while the app is in the background.

So what I want is the app to receive advertisement packets in

- high frequency when the app is in the foreground
- low frequency when the app is in the background

both in single code base, and be automatically switched. Is it possible? If it is, where should I write the codes written above?

Comment: You can use the same code in foreground and background except that you can't scan for `nil` in the background, only for a nominated service UUID. Also, unless you specify the allow duplicates key in your scan you will only receive a single call to `didDiscoverPeripheral`. What is your peripheral? Have you considered using iBeacons through core location rather than scanning through core Bluetooth?